# Export Pandas data frame with text column containg utf-8 text and URLs to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

My Pandas data frame consists of Tweets and meta data of each tweet (300.000 rows). Some of my colleagues need to work with this data in Excel which is why I need to export it.

I wanted to use either `.to_csv` or `.to_excel` which are both provided by Pandas but I can't get it to work properly.

When I use `.to_csv` my problem is that it keeps failing in the text part of the data frame. I've played around with different separators but the file is never 100% aligned. The text column seems to contain tabs, pipe characters etc. which confuses Excel.

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

When I try to use `.to_excel` together with the `xlsxwriter` engine I'm confronted with a different problem, which is that my text column contains to many URLs (I think). `xlswriter` tries to make special clickable links of these URLs instead of just handling them as strings. I've found some information on how to circumvent this but, again, I can't get it to work.

The following bit of code should be used to disable the function that I think is causing trouble:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})
```

However, when using `to_excel` I can't seem to adjust this setting of the Workbook object before I load the data frame into the Excel file.

In short how do I export a column with wildly varying text from a Pandas data frame to something that Excel understands?

**edit:**
example:

```
@geertwilderspvv @telegraaf ach Wilders toch, nep-voorzitter van een nep-partij met maar één lid, \nzeur niet over nep-premier of parlement!
```

So in this case It is obviously a line brake that is my data. I will try to find some more examples.

**edit2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error047600_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Er zijn fouten aangetroffen in bestand C:\Users\Guy Mahieu\Desktop\Vu ipython notebook\pandas_simple.xlsx</summary><removedRecords summary="Hier volgt een lijst van verwijderde records:"><removedRecord>Verwijderde records: Formule van het onderdeel /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

Translation of Dutch stuff:

Errors were found in "file".  Here follows a list of removed records: removed records: formula of the part  /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml

Comment: can you give us a sample of the df that doesn't work?

Comment: @JamesTobin I've added an example, I will add more if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible to pass XlsxWriter constructor options via the Pandas API but you can workaround the `strings_to_url` issue as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['http://python.org']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Don't convert url-like strings to urls.
writer.book.strings_to_urls = False

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Update**: In recent version of Pandas you can pass XlsxWriter constructor options to `ExcelWriter()` directly and you do not need to set `writer.book.strings_to_urls` indirectly:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_example.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})
```

See also [Passing XlsxWriter constructor options to Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas)

Comment: The code works so that is a great start. When I open the Excel file I get a warning that it needs to be recovered. I've put the log file in my post for better formatting.

Comment: You get a warning when you open the file created by my example?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I don't see any warning when I open the file and there really isn't any reason that there should be for such a simple test case. Also in relation to the warning you added above there isn't any "formula" part in `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. Did you add a formula or other data to the dataframe in the example?

Comment: Well I was testing it now on my full data frame. I've not added any formulas. To me the log warning seems empty. Apparently it is a known issue/bug: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/bugs.html  I will look into it further. You have been a great help!!

Comment: Perhaps there is some data in the dataframe that is being interpreted as a formula. Try adding the following at the same point as the other option to see if it makes a difference: `writer.book.strings_to_formulas= False`.

Comment: As of Pandas 2.1.1 it should be

```with pd.ExcelWriter(full_path, engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}}) as writer:
            outdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='monthly_data', index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(report_file, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False,
                                                                       'strings_to_formulas': False})
```