# Unable to open Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to automate some of my tasks in an excel sheet.

It includes **creating a pandas dataframe from an excel sheet** and then doing the necessary filtering and stuff and **writing the pandas dataframe to an excel sheet** which will be later **appended to another excel sheet** *(since pandas always creates a new excel sheet, removing all the other tabs from the existing excel file).*

The excel sheet from which dataframe is created is originally a csv file downloaded from a site. After the operations,I  write the dataframe to an excel sheet which when later is tried to open using pywin32 will throw an error "Open method of workbook class failed". Manually when I try to open the file, I get error dialog box
[image]

And clicking "yes", the excel opens in repaired version after removing xml content

SO, I figured out, this is why I cant open it using pywin32.

Opening using openpyxl works fine. But I need to use pywin32 for this purpose.

How can I open the excel file using pywin32?

Part of the code where I try to open the excel sheet :

```
import win32com.client
excel_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app.Interactive = False
excel_app.Visible = False
excel_app.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(main_file)
xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets('PSA Data')
row_count=xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
print("Last row in the sheet Data in the main file=",row_count)

copyBook=excel_app.Workbooks.Open("fullpath\dataframe.xlsx") # dataframe is the name of excel workbook which has some xml content
copySheet=copyBook.Worksheets('PSA_data')
copy_row_count=copySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
print("Last row in the Copy sheet =",copy_row_count)

copySheet.Range(copySheet.Cells(1,1),copySheet.Cells(copy_row_count+1,10)).Copy(xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(row_count,1),xlSheet.Cells(row_count+1,10)))   #copying data
xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=1)
copyBook.Close(SaveChanges=1)
del xlBook
del copyBook
excel_app.Quit()
del excel_app
```

Error

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: I have added a part of code

Comment: Please insert the code in the question as text instead of an image. In order for people to be able to help you, they must be able to copy your code text so they can run and test it. See also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: I feel, the xml content in the xlsx file is causing the error. How can I remove it from the file?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875238/export-pandas-data-frame-with-text-column-containg-utf-8-text-and-urls-to-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875238/export-pandas-data-frame-with-text-column-containg-utf-8-text-and-urls-to-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was due to xml content in the pandas dataframe. While converting dataframe to excel,I made the change like:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file,engine="xlsxwriter",options={'strings_to_formulas': False})
```

This solves the problem :)